# Custom Collection Implementation

Tags: c#, .net, validation

When implementing a custom collection that essentially wraps an existing .NET collection type you are required to implement the interface methods. All of which are obviously already implemented in the collection being wrapped. Is it ok to not validate method parameters being passed to the .NET implementation of that method, knowing that the .NET framework will validate them for you?

For example:

```
public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    => _values.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
```

Here, I allow .NET to validate the parameters for me. I could validate them myself no problem, but then if they do pass validation, the .NET list implementation is going to go through the same checks (null, index out of range etc...) a second time. This seems inefficient to me.

Is it ok to forgo validation in these circumstances?

Comment: You are only required to implement interface members (methods, properties, events, etc.) that belong to interfaces that you want to support. As for validation, what's "okay" or not is a matter of opinion. But I personally don't generally bother. Your opinion might be different if, for example, you want to ensure more informative exceptions (so e.g. user code sees the exception coming from your wrapper type and not the underlying type...the stack trace will have this information as well, but you can make it easier to see by throwing the exception yourself).

Comment: The difference between you throwing that exception and the underlying method throwing that exception is in this case basically "who is complaining" and this will be reflected in the stack trace attached to the exception. Here I wouldn't bother with validation *unless you have more stringent validation*. If, on the other hand, the underlying method would throw *different* exceptions, and you want your instead, then I definitely would do the validation.